# VS2012 compilation issues when using Trend Micro

Tags: visual-studio-2012, antivirus

I've been experiencing issues when trying to compile my project with VS2012 and Trend Micro antivirus installed on my machine, and I wanted to get some ideas as to why this is happening, if anyone else has been experiencing this, and possibly a solution.

Basically I have a project with a set of dependencies that compiles correctly when Trend Micro is disabled. When enabled, however, it seems to (often, but not always) cause one specific project to have its generated binary (.dll) deleted, which in turn causes dependent projects to fail compilation. The errors are of type:

58>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\XXX\bin\XYZ.dll' could not be found

58>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\XXX\bin\QWE.dll' could not be found

It's interesting to note:

- XYZ is the project that always fails;
- No logs or notifications are made by Trend Micro;
- No code changes are applied between tests of compiling with and/or without Trend Micro being enabled;
- This happens most often when requesting a Rebuild of the entire solution;

My VS12 is set to 4 parallel builds and versions are as follows:

Trend Micro OfficeScan Client (for Windows)

Version: 10.6.2108 SP1

-

Visual Studio Premium 2012

Version: 11.0.51106.01 Upgrade 1

Comment: Known issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759434/vs2012-parallel-build-produces-many-the-referenced-component-could-not-be-found-warnings

Comment: I have exactly the same problems using Visual Studio 2010 and Trend Micro OfficeScan. It seems me to be more related to Trend Micro.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I haven't found it useful to understand why anti-virus or other such software screws up. The fact is, it *does* screw up. My strategy has been to document it for the vendor and get them to fix their bug, or at least to give you a workaround.

Visual Studio differs from many other programs that the anti-virus vendors may be testing with. It opens and loads a large number of DLLs, for instance. It accesses a large number of files during a build. These are activities that an anti-virus or other security software might be very interested in.